# Powershell Is this Possible run an AD filter search and compare it to another list of users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Morning all, so what I am trying to achieve is that I do a Get-ADUser -Filter search seen below

but what I also want it to do is compare it to a list of users I have and if the user appears in the search I want it to not do anything with the users in List 1 but move all the accounts with the set amount of days to be moved to different ou I may be over complicating this so apologies. Any help or guidance would be appreciated

```
$Folder="C:\Temp"
$Days=10 
$ExportedReport = "$Folder\Report_10_days.csv" 
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $False} -SearchBase "OU=MY OU" -Properties SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)} | Sort | Select Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | export-csv $ExportedReport -nti
```

should I use something like Compare-Object to achieve this a little stuck on what to do next.

Comment: Where/how is the existing list stored? A CSV file? Simple txt file with a user name on each line?

Comment: Hi, its in a csv with only email addresses

Answer (score 1):

So first you need to import your .csv, so do that:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path "C:\folder\mydata.csv"
```

Then you need to cycle through each entry and get the full name from the mail address (I just assume your AD objects don't have the email) - and add a few variables to add multiple filters:

```
Foreach ($entry in $data) {
$newEmail = $entry.Split("@")[0]
$fullname = $newEmail.Split(".")[1] + " " + $newEmail.Split(".")[0]
$enabled = "Enabled"
$name = "Name"
Get-ADUser -Filter {$enabled -eq $False -and $name -like $fullname} -Properties SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)} | Sort | Select Name,SamAccountName,LastLogonDate | export-csv $ExportedReport -nti -Append
}
```

I added "-append" to the export-csv, since otherwise each iteration of the loop would erase the file instead of appending the entry.

Obviously, you still need the variables you defined before, for the Get-Aduser line, but otherwise this should do what you wanted.

The reason we use variables for the -filter is, that the syntax has troubles with interpreting whatever is stated in quotes when using more than one filter. In the .Split() command, the number in square brackets is the index of an array that is returned from split. If you split "Forename.Surname", you can imagine it being [0].[1].